# App Service with VNET integration cannot connect to HTTP endpoint within the same VNET

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have integrate my App service web app to an existing VNET in same region following this guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Within that VNET, there is already a Elasticsearch cluster running on VM scale sets and I can connect to Elasticsearch from a jumpbox VM within the same VNET via the private Ip http://10.0.0.4.

But the App service is not able not connect to the Elasticsearch via the private Ip address, following is error message:

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup`

Is this scenario supported by App service VNET integration? If yes, do I miss something? Or how to troubleshoot the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

App service VNET integration could support that scenario, read *Connecting Azure App services to Elasticsearch* in [this blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-and-kibana-deployments-on-azure). "With all this in place, the web application should be able to communicate with the cluster."

In that example, it uses [Gateway required VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#gateway-required-vnet-integration). Theoretically, the regional VNet Integration should also do the trick. You can go to your KUDU console for [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#troubleshooting). Also, you could check the following first.

[image]